WebView2 application freezes on calling async await from javascript
I have an application based on Microsoft Webview2 which is used to launch a web application in embedded mode. When I try to run any async code which blocks the main thread the entire application freezes, although the same javascript code works fine in any modern browser ( edge/chrome ).
I am trying to create a showModal dialog polyfill which has been deprecated now. And following the polyfill provided in official mdn page : https://github.com/niutech/showModalDialog/blob/gh-pages/showModalDialog.js

Code for window.showModalDialog polyfill I am using:
`


window.showModalDialog = window.showModalDialog || function(url, arg, opt)
      {
        url = url || ''; //URL of a dialog
        arg = arg || null; //arguments to a dialog
        opt = opt || 'dialogWidth:300px;dialogHeight:200px'; //options:         dialogTop;dialogLeft;dialogWidth;dialogHeight or CSS styles
        var caller = arguments.callee.caller.toString();
        var dialog = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('dialog'));
        dialog.setAttribute('style', opt.replace(/dialog/gi, ''));
        dialog.innerHTML = '<a href="#" id="dialog-close" style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 5px; font-size: 20px; color: #000; text-decoration: none; outline: none;">&times;</a><iframe id="dialog-body" src="' + url + '" style="border: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>';
        document.getElementById('dialog-body').contentWindow.dialogArguments = arg;
        document.getElementById('dialog-close').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            dialog.close();
        });
        dialog.showModal();
        //if using yield or async/await
        if(caller.indexOf('yield') >= 0 || caller.indexOf('await') >= 0) {
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                dialog.addEventListener('close', function() {
                    var returnValue = document.getElementById('dialog-body').contentWindow.returnValue;
                    document.body.removeChild(dialog);
                    resolve(returnValue);
                });
            });
        }


`

Code for testing the showModalDialog:

`
 var ret = await window.showModalDialog("demo-modal.html", "some argument", "dialogWidth:500px;dialogHeight:200px");
          document.getElementById('result2').innerText = "Returned from modal: " + ret;`

Here, when the flow reaches the await statement the entire application freezes and I am not able to use any keys/inputs.

This question is similar to: Why is window.showModalDialog deprecated? What to use instead?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I have clearly mentioned about the WebView2 application that freezes. And the showModalDialog API asynchronous code is what I am trying to achieve, which works in any modern browsers but does not work for WebView2 application.
